How does the Wald test follow a chi-square distribution? (Do we ignore independence)
So, according to the definition, a statistic follows a chi-square distribution if we square and add independent and standard normal variables right? So for the Wald test (Chi-square version), we are adding up squared coefficients and standardizing them, but they can't be independent right? So why is it still safe to assume they follow a chi-square distribution?

Can you be more specific and accurate on what"Wald test" you are referring to? No one really call "adding up squared coefficients and standardizing them" a "Wald test" (unless there is just one coefficient to be tested, say, in linear models).

(1) Not all chi-squared statistics arise as sums of squares of random variables. (2) Cochran's Theorem (search for it!) describes precisely how sums of squares of correlated random variables can nevertheless follow chi-squared distributions.  (3) Nobody is assuming a chi-squared distribution in the development of the theory: this is proven, usually under mild mathematical conditions and in an asymptotic sense (as the sample size grows arbitrarily large).

@whuber apologize if this is a silly question.. but for estimates/statistics that follow a chi-square distribution, do they still follow a chi-square distribution in the limit? or does it eventually converge to a normal distribution?

It depends on what you mean by "limit."  If the df increases without bound, then the chi-squared distribution gets closer and closer to Normal.  But if the df is fixed (or bounded), that only means the corresponding chi-squared distribution becomes a more accurate description of the null distribution of the statistic as more data are collected.

@whuber Thanks so much! Your comments are very helpful. Just one last question (sorry I'm pretty new to these topics so these might be dumb questions): When people say something follows a distribution under the null or as you said, "a more accurate description of the null distribution" does that mean the statistic will be useful to detect whether or not reject the null hypothesis, but we can't tell what distribution it will follow under the alternative hypothesis?

In many applications, the test statistic only approximately follows a chi-squared distribution.  This is the case for the chi-squared test of association in a contingency table, for instance: there are only a finite number of possible values the statistic can attain so it can't follow any continuous distribution.  But as the expected counts increase, the approximation grows ever better. // It's always the case that the test statistic follows a different distribution under $H_A:$ if it didn't, the test would be worthless.

@whuber I see.  So, essentially, we cannot determine the type of distribution the statistic will follow under the alternative hypothesis. However, our primary concern is whether we reject the null hypothesis. If we do, it suggests there is a high probability that the alternative hypothesis is correct?

No, that's not what I am saying.  Usually we can determine the distribution of the statistic under an alternative hypothesis.  The issue is that the distribution depends on which element of the alternative hypothesis is posited and usually the "alternative hypothesis" is a set with many different distributions.  Further, the chance of rejection isn't necessarily a "primary concern" and even when rejection occurs, we cannot say anything about the probability the alternative is correct, because aren't modeling the hypotheses as being random.

You might find the many posts at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31 to be relevant and helpful.

This works because of the special properties of the Normal distribution.  If a $p$-vector $Z$ has a multivariate Normal distribution then so does $AZ$ for any $q\times p$ matrix $A$.  In particular, if $Z$ has a multivariate Normal distribution with some linear constraints, so it has rank $q<p$, there will be a $q\times p$ matrix $A$ that makes $AZ$ uncorrelated and standard Normal. For multivariate Normal distributions, that's equivalent to being independent, so the sum of squares of the elements of $AZ$ will be a $\chi^2_q$.
None of this would work for general multivariate distributions, because a transformation that makes the elements uncorrelated typically wouldn't make them independent. But it does work for multivariate Normal distributions, and the central limit theorem guarantees us (approximate) multivariate Normal distributions in some circumstances.  That's why most $\chi^2$ tests (Wald or otherwise) work.
